# python elegant way to create folders and move files

Tags: python, pandas, file, operating-system, shutil

Currently, I have more than 30 `.xlsx` files in my source folder.

All these 30 files are from different regions in APAC which has keywords such as `IND`, `KOR`, `ASN` etc.

My objective is to do the below

a) create separate folders for each region (ASN, KOR and IND)

b) Copy `.xlsx` files with region keywords to appropriate folders.

So, I tried the below

```
if not os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\output_data\\IND'):
    os.mkdir('C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\output_data\\IND')
if not os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\output_data\\ASN'):
    os.mkdir('C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\output_data\\ASN')
if not os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\output_data\\KOR'):
    os.mkdir('C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\output_data\\KOR')
if not os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\output_data\\ASN_ANZ_KR'):
    os.mkdir('C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\output_data\\ASN_ANZ_KR')
    
source = 'C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\output_data'
IND = 'C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\output_data\\IND'
ASN = 'C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\output_data\\ASN'
KOR = 'C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\output_data\\KOR'
ASN_ANZ_KR = 'C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\output_data\\ASN_ANZ_KR'

files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
    if ("IND.xlsx" in f):
        shutil.move(f, IND)
    elif ("ASN.xlsx" in f) or ("ANZ.xlsx" in f):
        shutil.move(f, ASN)
    elif ("KOR.xlsx" in f):
        shutil.move(f, KOR)
    elif ("KR.xlsx" in f):
        shutil.move(f, ASN_ANZ_KR)
    else:
        a=0   # do nothing so, assign a dummy value to a variable
```

Though the above code works fine, is there any other better way to write this?

You can see i write multiple if conditions (multiple times) for creating folders and then to copy files based on wildcard.

Is there any better elegant and efficient approach available to do the above task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this, here is the annotated code:

```
from pathlib import Path

# mapping of filename match pattern to destination directory name
dct = {'IND': 'IND', 'ASN': 'ASN', 'KOR': 'KOR', 'KR': 'ASN_ANZ_KR'}

src = Path(source)
for key, val in dct.items():
    for file in src.glob(f'*{key}.xlsx'):
        # ensure destination directory exists
        dest = src / val
        dest.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

        # Move the file from source to destination
        file.rename(dest / file.name)
```

Comment: hi Shubham. May be slightly unrelated to this post. Can I know when can pandas create empty columns with name as nan? I am executing the same code in two different systems but I see that in one system, the output file has some random empty columns with nan as name? Is there anyway to find the rootcause of this? Everything else is same. Only the system is different and python versions are different etc.

Comment: I know we can drop using `df.loc[:, df.columns.notna()]` but is it possible to know why some `nan` columns are created. In my case, it is `nan` columns though. Or is it like we can never but write our code such a way to handle all these issues?

Comment: @TheGreat I don't think pandas can create nan's for empty column names.. generally it can only create `Unnamed column: ` while reading the files. Can you show the code snippet where the issue is being caused?

Comment: `df = pd.read_excel('MasterFile_final.xlsb',engine='pyxlsb')
df1 = pd.read_excel('Regions.xlsx')
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.iloc[1:]
df['ID_No'] = df['ID_No'].astype('float').astype('Int64')
merge_df = df.merge(df1,on=('ID_No'),how='inner')
#print(len(merge_df))
merge_df.to_csv('merge.csv',index=False)`

Comment: I pasted the code. The same code, works fine in my system. But when I run it in my friends system, it results in two `nan` columns (no name no data columns) in between all the columns. So, I delete them and use it for further processing. So, not sure what is the issue

Comment: when I open the `merge_df.csv` file in friends' system, I see two empty columns in excel `BI` and `BJ` column whereas in my system, it works fine. All my data gets over at `BJ` column. In my friends system, two columns exist at `BK` and `BL` because of empty column introduction in `BI` and `BJ`.

Comment: Code looks good..I suspect the issue might be related to bug in pandas dependencies in old version. create and venv and try to upgrade pandas on your friends computer then let me know if the issue still exists..

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue still prevails.. We upgraded pandas using --upgrade command..but it still doesn't resolve this issue. both use pandas 1.4.4

Comment: Can it also happen due to different python versions etc?